# Python Scrapy Shell Error While Scraping Wallmart

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping walmart.com using scrapy. when i am fetching https://www.walmart.com/ there is no error but when trying to fetch "https://www.walmart.com/search?q=tablets&typeahead=tabltes" the below error appears:
I have already disabled obey robot.text and employed scrapy fake user agents.

2024-02-14 09:42:25 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET [https://www.walmart.com/search?q=tablets&typeahead=tabltes>](https://www.walmart.com/search?q=tablets&typeahead=tabltes%3E)
2024-02-14 09:42:25 [py.warnings] WARNING: C:\Users\SADAM1\PycharmProjects\untitled4\v

```
import scrapy

class Wal1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "wal1"
    allowed_domains = ["walmart.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://walmart.com"]
    
    
    custom_settings = {
        "DOWNLOAD_DELAY": 6.3,
        "RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY": True,
        "COOKIES_ENABLED": False,
        "AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED": True,
        "AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY ": 2,
        "AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY": 11.7,
        "AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY": 1,
        "CONCURRENT_REQUESTS": 4,
        "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY": False,
    }
    def parse(self, response):

        pass
```

env\lib\site-packages\scrapy_fake_useragent\middleware.py:95: ScrapyDeprecation
Warning: Attribute RetryMiddleware.EXCEPTIONS_TO_RETRY is deprecated. Use the RETRY_EXCEPTIONS setting instead.
if isinstance(exception, self.EXCEPTIONS_TO_RETRY) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeTg0.png)

i have tried disabling robot.text obey and employed scrapy fake user agents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Scrapy shell, then the settings you define in your spider aren't used. You could try passing that specific option when using `scrapy shell` through the `--set` flag which *sets/overrides settings*;

```
$ scrapy shell --set="ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False"
```

once there;

```
fetch("https://www.walmart.com/search?q=tablets&typeahead=tablte")
# 2024-02-14 19:24:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
# 2024-02-14 19:24:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.walmart.com/search?q=tablets&typeahead=tablte> (referer: None)
```

Comment: even if i disabled it in scrapy shell and in setting also. will my spider be able to crawl this website ???

Comment: yes , it worked in scrapy shell but the same error appears when crawling.

Comment: What are you exactly trying? I can't see you're requesting other URL than walmart.com from your spider?

Comment: @SadamShah "even if i disabled it in scrapy shell and in setting also.", the scrapy shell works independent of your settings as do spiders. Whatever you do in the shell has no implications on the spiders and viceversa.

Comment: it worked by disabling robottext obey.